# How to handle Integer Division By Zero exception using Boost.Test library?

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, boost-test, divide-by-zero

I'm writing unit tests using Boost.Test against some old C math library. One of tested functions in known to raise Integer Division By Zero system exception for some specified input. Let's say it's desired behavior and I want to write negative test for this case.

`BOOST_REQUIRE_THROW(statement, exception);` is not working for me as it is not C++ style exception (this macro is using `try {} catch {}` internally).

What is the correct way to handle case when I'm expecting failure on system level?

Comment: If it's on Windows, you may use Structured Exception Handling (SEH) to catch div by 0.

Comment: Yes, it's Windows. I could use SEH but I would prefer some Boost-based solution if there is any.

Comment: @Mickey I do not think there is going to be an OS-independent solution because last I remember POSIX(Linux + Mac) does not allow you to continue after a divide by zero error. You would have to go through alot of effort in starting a separate process, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's Windows, I suggest looking into [_set_se_translator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Windows API. It allows to handle Structured Exception with C++ `catch`.

There are other possible ways, such is installing your handlers, but this one allows uniform exception handling as if they were C++ exceptions with minimal programming effort.

Comment: Ok, I think I will look deeper into this. I think I can get similar effect by setting "Enable C++ exceptions" to "Yes with SEH Exceptions (/EHa)" in Visual Studio project options.